# Android display files from URL GET

Tags: android, file, webview

I'm working on the Android version of an app I did for iOS.  I have some files (could be PDF, DOC, PNG, etc) in cloud storage and I retrieve them using an ASPX handler (like http://www.myserver.com/GetFile?name=test.png).

The goal is to DISPLAY ONLY, not download the files.

In iOS I used a UIWebView and it would download and preview the file as long as the OS could handle that file type.

What is the best approach for Android?  I've tried the following:

- WebView and embedding in google docs (http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=) - DOES NOT WORK FOR PNG
- Launching a new Activity using myIntent.setDataAndType(myFileURI, myFileMIME); where myFileMIME = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(myFileTypeExtension).  For PNGS I get "No activity for type image/png"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) for this.

Comment: But I don't want to download the file, I just want to display it for the user.

Answer (score 0):

The second option is a better way for Android, after fetching the file from cloud.

Use MimeType as "image/*", which usually works for all images and opens in default gallery.

Comment: But I need this to be generic for multiple different MIME types.  Are you suggesting detecting it's image/<some type> and changing the type to "*" only for images?

Comment: As further info - I have tried this method a couple ways and have it now with just intent.setData(myFileURI) instead of explicitly setting the MIME type.

What happens is whether PDF or PNG, it starts a download in the download manager and comes back to the app.  I really want to view the file, NOT download it.

Comment: Ok, this was a suggestion based on non-generic/all viewing of images on Android. However to view them online you should have the link (image url) of the file and launch them in webview/customized webview. Let me know if you need some code for that.

Comment: I would LOVE to see some code on how to do this with a webview @Kay.  One of the problems is it isn't just images; need DOC & PDF support.  Another problem is I don't have a direct link to the file; it's a webhandler that returns to file to me based on a file ID.

Answer (score 0):

So what I've ended up doing is classifying the MIME type as shown above.  If the type is "image/*" then I display the image directly in a WebView.

If the type is "application/*" then I embed it in google docs using the 1st method, and display it in the WebView.

Still looking for a better solution.